# Update key value of an object inside Dynamo DB

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have the following object saved into Dynamo DB.

```
   const obj =  {
        data:{
            src:"s3://some_bucket_name/folder/foo.html",
            dest:"s3://some_bucket_name/folder/bar.pdf"
        },
        op: "someFunc",
        status: "not started"

    }
```

This works, and my data is being saved in DynamoDB.
However, I want to update the **status** of the data in another place and change it to **started**.

This is the code I have for updating the **status** but it doesnt work.
It says "unexpected key found in params.Key[status]"

```
          const params = {
                TableName: 'tableName',
                Key: {
                    "status": record.dynamodb.Keys.Document.S
                },
                UpdateExpression: "SET started = :started",
                ExpressionAttributeValues: {
                    ":started": "started"
                },
                ReturnValues: "UPDATED_NEW"
            }


          db.updateItem(params).promise()
            .then(data => console.log(data, 'updated data data'))
            .catch(err => console.log(err, 'err updating item'))
```

I checked other examples on SO and online but I couldnt make it work, can anyone point me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Key` should reference the primary key attribute of your table. I don't believe the `status` field is the table's primary key.

The `status` field belongs in the `UpdateExpression` like

```
UpdateExpression: "SET status = :started",
```

Comment: This was what I was doing wrong, thank you for the calrification!